# How to save grid filter state across page loads?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'd like for the state of filters, rearranged/resized/sorted columns, etc to be saved across page loads.

I've seen the [stateId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-stateId) property but I am not sure how to use it.
Any help on this?

I have set the following properties under my grid :

```
stateful : true,
stateId: 'myGrid',
stateEvents: ['columnhide', 'columnmove', 'columnresize', 'columnshow', 'sortchange'],
```

I also added this at the end of Ext.OnReady() :

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
    expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have, add `Ext.state.*` in `Ext.require` function then ;

```
// add the following definition after Ext.onReady
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
    expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
}));

// specify statefull and stateId property of the components
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    stateful : true,
    stateId: 'combobox-one'
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Manager' of undefined` although I have added `Ext.require('Ext.state.*');`

Comment: And also, you have mentioned, you should specify only `stateId` property for `filtersfeature`. There isn't `statefull` property for filtersfeature.

Comment: I managed to make it work. I'm facing a different problem now. Whenever I change the sorting of a column to ascending or descending and then reload the page I get this error : `Uncaught Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.`

Comment: Have you tried to move `Ext.state.Manager` just below to `Ext.onReady`

Comment: About url problem, I think you are trying to call a method/function over a component but there is no proxy definition in the model, is that right? As I said, just copy+paste your full code. I can't reproduce the problem without this!